# Fatal error: Call to a member function initCache() while moving site

Tags: magento-1.9

*Moving Magento Website  from Localhost to Production Server*
I have tried deleted the cache,session & updated my config core table with the right values

**Fatal error:**

> Call to a member function initCache() on a non-object in /home/domain/public_html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 609

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see any new entries in log folder, apart from this error ?

Comment: Yes, Please check [link](http://pastebin.com/pv7HYgAr)

Comment: These are latest warnings/errors from /log/system.log

Comment: See, if that said file exists at the location or not, seems like a corrupt download.